# Remember tree Navigation state with jquery cookie

Tags: jquery, css, cookies, navigation

Hi I have a basic expandable tree navigation that is driven by jquery. I'd like to be able to remember the state of the menu when the user navigates to a new page as at the moment it collapses back to its original closed state. Here is my jquery for the tree navigation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('ul li.parent').children('.closed').addClass('expand');

$(".tree_nav li a.expand").toggle(           

      function() { // START FIRST CLICK FUNCTION
          $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown()
          if ($(this).hasClass('closed')) {   
              $(this).removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
          }
      }, // END FIRST CLICK FUNCTION

      function() { // START SECOND CLICK FUNCTION
          $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp()

          if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
              $(this).removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
          }
      } // END SECOND CLICK FUNCTIOn
); // END TOGGLE FUNCTION 
}); // END DOCUMENT READY
```

Basically I'm just adding a class of 'open' when a link is clicked and animating on that class. All I need to do is remember which items have the "open" class when the used navigates to a new page. I believe the best solution would be using the jquery cookie plugin which I've had a play with but so far I've been unsuccessful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Is there any server side processing behind your menu?

Comment: Yeah its just a Wordpress wp_list_pages function that's listing all the pages of a custom post type in a nested list. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are classes added by default to the current Pages for the wp_list_pages function, see here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes on the Classes section. So you could propably use this classes as well to style your navigation.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer but styling isn't the issue. I'm applying a class with Jquery to expand the nested list that WordPress creates and I want to maintain the state when navigating to a new page.

Comment: I just suggested you use the same class Wordpress uses to expand your list. I suppose that after the navigation Wordpress will have set it's own classes to the menu to indicate the current state.

Answer (score 0):

Within your wp_list_pages function you could add an "open" class to the page your on.

Then in your jQuery use .hasClass("open") to open then menu, otherwise close it.